# how to get absolute xpath from a relative xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I can find an object with a relative xpath. is there a way I can get it's absolute path?
something like absXpath = weblelement.getxpath();
working in c#.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but when you inspect the element you can copy the full xpath i.e. copy -> copy full xpath

Comment: i know how to get the full path manually, but I need to get it programaly. thing is, the full path changes dynamically, so i cant use it to find the element. but i still need the full path.